# reset only one chzn-select dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I would like to reset all dropdown I would do

```
$(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

however if I have

```
<select id='NAME_OF_THIS' name='NAME_OF_THIS' data-placeholder='Select something' class='chzn-select'  style='width:300px;' tabindex='4'> 
        <option value='0' selected='selected'></option>
            <option value='1'>1</option> 
            <option value='2'>2</option> 
            <option value='3'>3</option> 

        </select>
```

What line of code resets only specific dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `id` attribute to uniquely identify the desired select element and then reset it

```
$("#NAME_OF_THIS").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
```